# How to match group 1 in a regex followed by a 0 rather than matching group 10

Tags: regular-expression, gedit

In regex plugin of gedit, I use a regex to match/search and another for substitution. In the matching regex, I only have one group. In the substitution regex, I use \1 to refer to the group, and I also like to add a zero right behind \1, but \10 will change to mean the 10th group in matching regex. So I was wondering how to solve this problem?

For example, in my original text there are cases where `0` is misinput as `o`, such as `12o` should be `120`. My matching regex is `(\d+)o`, and my substitution regex is `\10` which is not right.

Comment: It depends on the regexp engine. Which plugin are you using (there are several around)?

Comment: It is Python-style regex, written by Daniel d'Andrada T. de Carvalho <daniel.carvalho@indt.org.br>, Ben Fisher halfhourhacks.blogspot.com

Comment: `\1[0]` should do it in pretty much every implementation. (So that's a character class consisting of a single character, without quantifiers like `?` or `*`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that plugin uses the same syntax as the [Python regexp engine](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub): use `\g<1>0` as the replacement text.